# Isn't lambda function also an object with Function1 trait?

Tags: scala

```
object MyApp {
  def printValues(f: {def apply(x: Int): Int}, from: Int, to: Int): Unit = {
    println(
      (from to to).map(f(_)).mkString(" ")
    )
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val anonfun1 = new Function1[Int, Int] {
      final def apply(x: Int): Int = x * x
    }

    val fun1 = (x:Int)=>x*x
    printValues(fun1, 3, 6)
  }
}
```

I thought that lambda function in scala is also an object that extends the Function1 trait. However this code fails for `printValues(fun1, 3, 6)` and not `printlnValues(anonfun1, 3, 6)`. Why is that so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a very interesting question to explore. There is a saying that one should never rely on implementation detail in code, I think this is borderline of doing that.

Let's try and break down what happens here.

### Structural Types:

When you require a structural type, such as you did in this method:

```
def printValues(f: {def apply(x: Int): Int}, from: Int, to: Int): Unit = {
  println(
    (from to to).map(f(_)).mkString(" ")
  )
}
```

What Scala does is use reflection to try and find the `apply` method at run-time, and dynamically invoke it. It gets translated to something that looks like this:

```
public static Method reflMethod$Method1(final Class x$1) {
    MethodCache methodCache1 = Tests$$anonfun$printValues$1.reflPoly$Cache1.get();
    if (methodCache1 == null) {
        methodCache1 = (MethodCache)new EmptyMethodCache();
        Tests$$anonfun$printValues$1.reflPoly$Cache1 = new SoftReference((T)methodCache1);
    }
    Method method1 = methodCache1.find(x$1);
    if (method1 != null) {
        return method1;
    }
    method1 = ScalaRunTime$.MODULE$.ensureAccessible(x$1.getMethod("apply", (Class[])Tests$$anonfun$printValues$1.reflParams$Cache1));
    Tests$$anonfun$printValues$1.reflPoly$Cache1 = new SoftReference((T)methodCache1.add(x$1, method1));
    return method1;
}
```

This is the decompiled Java code that gets emitted. Long story short, it looks for the `apply` method.

### What happens in Scala <= 2.11

For any Scala version prior 2.12, declaring an anonymous function results in the compiler generating a class extending `AbstractFunction*`, where `*` is the arity of the function. These abstract function classes inherit in turn `Function*`, and implement their `apply` method with the implementation of the lambda.

So for example, if we take your expression:

```
val fun1 = (x:Int) => x * x
```

The compiler emits for us:

```
val fun2: Int => Int = {
    @SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class $anonfun extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp with Serializable {
      def <init>(): <$anon: Int => Int> = {
        $anonfun.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      final def apply(x: Int): Int = $anonfun.this.apply$mcII$sp(x);
      <specialized> def apply$mcII$sp(x: Int): Int = x.*(x)
    };
    (new <$anon: Int => Int>(): Int => Int)
  };
  ()
```

When we look at the bytecode level, we see the generated anonymous class and it's `apply` methods:

```
Compiled from "Tests.scala"
public final class othertests.Tests$$anonfun$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp implements scala.Serializable {
  public static final long serialVersionUID;

  public final int apply(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: invokevirtual #21                 // Method apply$mcII$sp:(I)I
       5: ireturn

  public int apply$mcII$sp(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: iload_1
       2: imul
       3: ireturn

So what happens when you request the `apply` method at runtime? The run-time will see that theirs a method defined on `$anonfun` called `apply` which takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`, which is exactly what we want and invoke it. All is good and everyone's happy.
```

### Lo and Behold, Scala 2.12

In Scala 2.12, we get something called SAM conversion. SAM types is a feature in Java 8 which allows you to abbreviate implementing an interface, and instead supply a lambda expression. For example:

```
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Yay in lambda!")).start();
```

Instead of having to implement `Runnable` and override `public void run`.
Scala 2.12 set a goal to be compatible with SAM types via SAM conversion when possible.

In our particular case, a SAM conversion is possible, meaning that instead of Scala's `Function1[Int, Int]` we get a specialized version of `scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcII$sp`. This `JFunction` is compatible with Java, and has the following structure:

```
package scala.runtime.java8;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface JFunction1$mcII$sp extends scala.Function1, java.io.Serializable {
    int apply$mcII$sp(int v1);

    default Object apply(Object t) { return scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(apply$mcII$sp(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(t))); }
}
```

This `JFunction1` has been specialized (like we use the @specialized annotation in Scala) to emit a special method for `def apply(i: Int): Int`. Note one important factor here, that this method only implements an `apply` method of the form `Object => Object`, not `Int => Int`. Now we can start getting a feeling as to why this could be problematic.

Now, when we compile the same example in Scala 2.12, we see:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val fun2: Int => Int = {
    final <artifact> def $anonfun$main(x: Int): Int = x.*(x);
    ((x: Int) => $anonfun$main(x))
  };
  ()
```

We no longer see a method extending `AbstractFunction*`, we simply see method called `$anonfun$main`. When we look at the generated bytecode, we see that internally, it'll call `JFunction1$mcII$sp.apply$mcII$sp(int v1);`:

```
public void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
    0: invokedynamic #41,  0  // InvokeDynamic #0:apply$mcII$sp: ()Lscala/runtime/java8/JFunction1$mcII$sp;
    5: astore_2
    6: return
```

Yet if we explicitly extends `Function1` ourselves and implement `apply`, we get the a similar behavior to previous Scala version, but not an exact identical:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val anonfun1: Int => Int = {
    final class $anon extends AnyRef with Int => Int {
      def <init>(): <$anon: Int => Int> = {
        $anon.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      final def apply(x: Int): Int = x.*(x)
    };
    new $anon()
  };
  {
    ()
  }
}
```

We no longer extend `AbstractFunction*`, but we do have an `apply` method which satisfies the structural type condition during run-time. At the bytecode level, we see an `int apply(int)`, an `object apply(object)` and a bunch of cases for the @specialization attribute annotating `Function*`:

```
public final int apply(int);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: iload_1
     2: invokevirtual #183                // Method apply$mcII$sp:(I)I
     5: ireturn

public int apply$mcII$sp(int);
  Code:
     0: iload_1
     1: iload_1
     2: imul
     3: ireturn

public final java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: aload_1
     2: invokestatic  #190                // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
     5: invokevirtual #192                // Method apply:(I)I
     8: invokestatic  #196                // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    11: areturn
```

### Conclusion:

We can see that there's a change in the **implementation detail** of how the Scala compiler treats lambda expressions under some circumstances. Is this a bug? my feelings tends towards a no. In no where does the Scala specification guarantee that there needs to be a method named `apply` which matches the signature of the lambda, that is why we call it an *implementation detail*. Although this is indeed an interesting quirk, I would not rely on such code in any sort of production environment as it is subject to change.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm not fully getting exactly what the problem is.
Your code seems to work as well.

But the line

> I thought that lambda function in scala is also an object that extends the Function1

is correct if Scala version is < 2.12

Function literal in scala is just a syntactic sugar of FunctionN which are Function1 to Function22.
So the below code is exactly the same.

```
val f: Int=> Int = new Function1[Int, Int] {
    def apply(x:Int): Int = x * x
}

val f2: Int => Int = (x: Int) => x * x
```

If you want to check both of them works as FunctionN,your code `printValues` should've be like this

```
def printValues(f: (Int) => Int, from: Int, to: Int): Unit = {
     println((from to to).map(f).mkString(" "))
}
//or
def printValues(f: Function1[Int,Int], from: Int, to: Int): Unit = {
     println((from to to).map(f).mkString(" "))
}
```

Once again, because of the syntactic sugar, they are the same meaning.
Your definition of a parameter type is `AnyRef{def apply(x: Int): Int}` So

```
object Foo {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = x * x
}
```

can be used for `printValues`.

If you working on Scala 2.12, It's bit different story.

If your function literal meets some conditions, It'll be converted into SAM type automatically.
For more detail, check this [sam-conversion](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html?_ga=1.257098827.1927544172.1478660225#sam-conversion)

**EDITED**
You must be using 2.12 because the code work fine if it's on a 2.11 or eariler.
like I mentioned in the last, It's all because of the sam-conversion.
fix `printValues`'s parameter into `(Int) => Int` or `Function1[Int,Int]` to define explicitly to use `FunctionN`

Comment: If you run his code, you'll see that at run-time an exception is thrown for a missing `apply` method.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The code worked in both REPL and compile run in 2.11.8

Comment: I think OP is compiling using 2.12

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It seems so, I edited the answer.thanks for the info.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how SAM conversion changes the behavior?

Comment: I will be checking exactly why his code triggers the conversion later though, I'll be grateful if you can post another answer or modify this if you can

Comment: Added an answer, this was a fun exploration.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a method on an instance of a structural type involves runtime reflection.

For `val f: { def apply(i: Int): Int} = (x: Int) => x * x` the call `f(10)` (or `f.apply(10)`) is resolved to something like `f.getClass.getMethod("apply", classOf[Int]).invoke(f, 10)`.

And a lambda has such a method in Scala 2.11.8 (and `Function1` still has it in 2.12.1, so your code works fine with `anonfun1`):

```
scala> val f: { def apply(i: Int): Int } = (x: Int) => x * x
f: AnyRef{def apply(i: Int): Int} = <function1>

scala> f.getClass.getMethods.filter(_.getName == "apply") foreach println
public final int $line11.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(int)
public final java.lang.Object $line11.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(java.lang.Object)
```

But in 2.12.1 it has only the method that takes an `Object`:

```
scala> val f: { def apply(i: Int): Int } = (x: Int) => x * x
f: AnyRef{def apply(i: Int): Int} = $$Lambda$1015/1912769093@364b1061

scala> f.getClass.getMethods.filter(_.getName == "apply") foreach println
public default java.lang.Object scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcII$sp.apply(java.lang.Object)
```

It can still be invoked, of course:

```
scala> f.getClass.getMethod("apply", classOf[AnyRef]).invoke(f, Int.box(10)).asInstanceOf[Int]
res2: Int = 100
```

But doesn't work with standard structural type method invocation.

---

I believe this is a bug in the Scala standard library. Lambdas in 2.12.1 are represented by instances of `scala.runtime.java8.JFunction*` classes. For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface JFunction1$mcDF$sp extends scala.Function1, java.io.Serializable {
    double apply$mcDF$sp(float v1);

    default Object apply(Object t) { return scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble(apply$mcDF$sp(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToFloat(t))); }
}
```

And I don't see a reason why those don't have a specialized method, similar to the one generated for `scala.Function*` traits:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface JFunction1$mcDF$sp extends scala.Function1, java.io.Serializable {
    double apply$mcDF$sp(float v1);

    default Object apply(Object t) { return scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble(apply$mcDF$sp(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToFloat(t))); }

    default double apply(float t) { return apply$mcDF$sp(t); }
}
```